# Get rid of extra padding on page

Tags: header, padding, space

I have a Wordpress blog and each page has this extra space/padding on top that I want to get rid of. I have a Custom CSS plugin installed. Anyone have suggestions for how to get rid of it??

chasemymuse.com

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Perhaps a screenshot with the padding circled/highlighted or the HTML/CSS that's causing the issue.

Comment: You need to show us the Screenshot of it as @BartJedrocha said

Comment: What do you mean with "Custom CSS plugin"? Are you not able to edit the CSS directly?

Comment: how do I insert a screenshot?

Comment: this is Wordpress, it's not recommended to edit the CSS directly because if the theme is updated, you lose all the changes you made. So we download plugins to make changes.